# How to iterate a list and join specific elements in Python?

Tags: python, list, iteration

Suppose we have a list `l = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, ...]` I would like to group elements from that list such that:

```
(1, 5, 9)
(2, 6, 10)
(3, 7, 11)
(4, 8, 12)
```

and so on. (Taking into account that the length of the list is always a multiple of 3)

Have tried the following but of course this just groups the elements consecutively:

```
>>>for x, y, z in itertools.zip_longest(*[iter(lista)] * 3):
    print(x,y,z)
>>>(1 2 3)

(4 5 6)

(7 8 9)

(10 11 12)
```

The desired output:
`(1, 5, 9) (2, 6, 10) (3, 7, 11) (4, 8, 12)`

**Updated Question**
Let me "upgrade" the question to my specific approach:
So, I have a list of 900 numpy arrays, I would like to group these arrays in sub-lists which length is 3. Hence, there will be a final list containing 300 sub-lists, where each sub-list contains 3 arrays.
These arrays shall be grouped in the way mentioned above.
The desired output, if we have a list of 900 numbers, should be:
`(1, 5, 9) (2, 6, 10) (3, 7, 11) (4, 8, 12) (13, 17, 21) (14, 18, 22) (15, 19, 23) (16, 20, 24) (25, 29, 33) (26, 30, 34) (27, 31, 35) (28, 32, 36)...`

Comment: If the list has more than 12 elements, do you want four larger tuples, or (which seems more likely) more triples of more widely-spaced values?

Comment: Okay, I have a list of 900 elements, I want to group them into 300 sub-lists where each of these should have 3 elements, ordered in the way described in the post.

Comment: Just to clarify a bit more, the list consists of 900 numpy arrays.

Comment: I think @yatu's answer has you covered.

Comment: So for the 900 elements scenario, what's the supposed space? `(1, 301, 601)`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Original answer

You can achieve the same using `list slicing` and simple `for` loop over a range

```
# Input
set_of_data = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12]
# Capture every 4th element in a sequence starting from 0th index, hence set number_of_rows = 4
number_of_rows = 4
# Loop through the range(4) --> [0,1,2,3] and each time collect data by jumping 4 positions
res = [set_of_data[i::number_of_rows] for i in range(number_of_rows)]
# Printing result
print (res)
# Output
# [[1, 5, 9], [2, 6, 10], [3, 7, 11], [4, 8, 12]]
```

I hope this helps and counts!

> Updated Answer as requested.

```
    # Input
set_of_data = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13,14,15,16,17,18, 19,20,21,22,23,24]
# Defining variables
len_of_data = len(set_of_data)
number_of_rows = 4
number_of_group = 12

# Main code
res = [ tuple(set_of_data[i:i+number_of_group][j::number_of_rows])  for  i in range(0,len_of_data, number_of_group) for j in range(number_of_rows) ]

# Output
print (res)
# [(1, 5, 9), (2, 6, 10), (3, 7, 11), (4, 8, 12), (13, 17, 21), (14, 18, 22), (15, 19, 23), (16, 20, 24)]
```

I request you to close the answer if you are satisfied with any of the answers.

Comment: Output is not as the required one.

Comment: Updated the answer after correct interpretation of the question.

Comment: what does the number_of_group represents in your code?

Answer (score 3):

You could use a list comprehension, slicing as many times as the list size divided by the step size:

```
step = 4
[l[i::step] for i in range(len(l)//(step-1))]
# [[1, 5, 9], [2, 6, 10], [3, 7, 11], [4, 8, 12]]
```

Comment: Thanks, would this be applicable for what I want regarding the updated description in the post of the question? Namely, a new list of lists, where each sub-list contains 3 numpy arrays in the same fashion of grouping, that is, [[1, 5, 9], [2, 6, 10], [3, 7, 11], [4, 8, 12].....]

Comment: Please share a small sample and expected output so it's easier to help @user

Comment: Unfortunately no, in that case it'll become `[[1, 5, 9, 13, 17,...], [[2, 6, 10, 14, 18, 22,...]...]`. But it's not clear in your question how your desired output on actual data should look like.

Comment: @yatu I updated my question in the post, please give it a check, thank you! :)

Answer (score 1):

## Final answer:

If you want to not repeat elements, try this instead:

```
import numpy as np
l = list(range(1, 301))
step = 4
length = 3
size = step * length
result = np.array(l).reshape(len(l) // size, length, step).transpose(0, 2, 1).reshape(len(l) // length, length)
```

Result:

```
array([[  1,   5,   9],
       [  2,   6,  10],
       [  3,   7,  11],
       [  4,   8,  12],
       [ 13,  17,  21],
       [ 14,  18,  22],
       [ 15,  19,  23],
       [ 16,  20,  24],
       [ 25,  29,  33],
       ...
       [277, 281, 285],
       [278, 282, 286],
       [279, 283, 287],
       [280, 284, 288],
       [289, 293, 297],
       [290, 294, 298],
       [291, 295, 299],
       [292, 296, 300]])
```

## Updated Original answer:

Based on your clarified requirement, you can do this instead:

```
step = 4
result = [l[i:i+step*2+1:step] for i in range(len(l)-step*2)]
```

Result:

```
[[1, 5, 9], 
 [2, 6, 10], 
 [3, 7, 11], 
 ...
 [290, 294, 298],
 [291, 295, 299],
 [292, 296, 300]]
```

Explanation:

```
step = 4  # the spacing between each element in the     
                                            # ┌ loop from 0 to 2 steps before list ends (300 - 8 = 292)
result = [l[i:i+step*2+1:step] for i in range(len(l)-step*2)]
#         │ │ │          └ skip every step (4)
#         │ │ └ end after step occured twice (8); the +1 is needed because end index is not returned.
#         │ └ start from index i (0, 1, 2,... 291, 292)
#         └ slice list l into a triplet
```

## Original answer:

Seeing as you are already using `numpy` for the 900 elements, you can just do this:

```
np.array(l).reshape(3, len(l)//3).T
```

Which gives you:

```
array([[ 1,  5,  9],
       [ 2,  6, 10],
       [ 3,  7, 11],
       [ 4,  8, 12]])
```

If you need it back as a `list` you can just do `.tolist()`:

```
np.array(l).reshape(3, len(l) //3).T.tolist()
# [[1, 5, 9], [2, 6, 10], [3, 7, 11], [4, 8, 12]]
```

Comment: Seems like this can work out. Nevertheless, lets create a list of 300 numbers `l2 = list(range(1, 300))` running the snippet `np.array(l).reshape(3, len(l) //3).T.tolist()` I get something like: [[1, 101, 201], [2, 102, 202], [3, 103, 203],...] But the desired should be[[1,5,9], [[2, 6, 10], [3, 7, 11], ..]

Comment: @user3885769 I've updated the answer based on your clarification.

Comment: @r.rook thanks, grouping a list of 300 elements should give a resulting list of 30 elements (in this case, it gives a 292 of length). Namely, when running the code provided in your answer, things go well in the first 4 elements: [1, 5, 9], [2, 6, 10], [3, 7, 11], [4, 8, 12] but then, e.g., on the 5th one: [5, 9, 13], the number 5 is repeated again, on the 6th [6, 10, 14] the number 6 also, and so on. The desired output shall be: [[1, 5, 9], [2, 6, 10], [3, 7, 11], [4, 8, 12], [13, 17, 21], etc] So that we don't iterate the first elements again, ending, in this case, in a list of 30.

Comment: In the future please keep in mind to provide and clarify the exact details required in your question, as it's easy to be open to interpretation.  Regardless, please see my updated answer.  Using `numpy`'s `transpose` and `reshape` seems to be the easiest solution in this case.